# ERROR PHP PHP Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código y me da este error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SECTOR in /var/www/html/fcstbk/pipeline_phpcode.php on line 915, referer: http://localhost/fcstbk/pipeline.php?servicio=pipelineNoEdit

El código es el siguiente:

```
function leerCUSTOMER ($conn, $servicio)
    {
    $customerName    = array()                               ;

    $sql_tira   = "SELECT id, CUSTOMER FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ACTIVE = 1 ;" ;

    $resultado  = QueryBD ($conn, $sql_tira)            ;

    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
        {       
        $customerName[$row['id']]    = $row['CUSTOMER']  ;
        }

    return $customerName    ;
    }
```

```
function leerSECTOR ($conn, $servicio)
    {
    $SECTORName    = array()                               ;

    $sql_tira   = "SELECT id FROM SECTOR ;" ;

    $resultado  = QueryBD ($conn, $sql_tira)            ;

    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
        {       
        $SECTORName[$row['id']]    = $row['SECTOR']  ;
        }

    return $SECTORName  ;
    }
```

El de customer me funciona pero el de SECTOR no

Comment: Coloca el error en la pregunta, también te recomiendo que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas plantear mejor tu pregunta, además haz el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ganarás una medalla

Answer (score 1):

No te funciona porque no estás seleccionando la columna `SECTOR` en la instrucción SQL.

Prueba así:

```
function leerSECTOR ($conn, $servicio) {
    $SECTORName = array() ;
    $sql_tira = "SELECT id, SECTOR FROM SECTOR";
    $resultado = QueryBD ($conn, $sql_tira);
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $SECTORName[$row['id']]  = $row['SECTOR'];
    }
    return $SECTORName;
}
```

No sé si sabes que se pueden guardar los datos así también:

```
function leerSECTOR ($conn, $servicio) {
    $SECTORName = array() ;
    $sql_tira = "SELECT id, SECTOR FROM SECTOR";
    $resultado = QueryBD ($conn, $sql_tira);
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $SECTORName[]  = $row;
    }
    return $SECTORName;
}
```

Comment: Hola Cedano gracias por tu interes sigue fallando igual con las 2 opciones ya me estoy volviendo loco no se que hacer

Comment: @andresbugarini será entonces que la columna se llama de otro modo. Pon la consulta así: `SELECT * FROM SECTOR`  y dentro del `while` haz un `var_dump($row);` para ver qué muestra. O revísalo en la base de datos, que la tabla y columnas se llamen así y que tengan datos.